# Nested IF Statement Not Giving Correct Range - Excel

Tags: excel-formula

Can someone please take a look at this if statement and tell me whats wrong with it? I'm trying to make it input an answer depending on where the percentage lies within the table. Here's the table:

**1st Column**

65% 
75% 
80% 
85% 
90%
95%

**2nd Column**

0.60 %
1.70 %
2.40 %
2.80 %
3.10 %
4.00 %

Here's my nested if statement:

=IF(K2<=65%,J2*0.6%,IF(K2<=75%,J2*1.7%,IF(K2<=80%,J2*2.4%,IF(K2<=85%,J2*2.8%,IF(K2<=90%,J2*3.1%,**IF(K2<=95%,J2*4%**))))))

91.38% == k2

$319722 == J2

What this is doing for some reason is $319722*4% (bolded where it is in the if statement).

What it should be doing is printing $319722*3.1% since it's falling between the ranges of 90% - 94.99999999...

I tried changing it around to be >= but then it would give me a different number but it always focuses on 1 percentage range. I need it to scan and stop and the correct percent.

I can't figure out what is wrong with this so if anyone can help, i'd greatly appreciate it

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`=IF(K2>=95%,J2*4%,IF(K2>=90%,J2*3.1%,IF(K2>=85%,J2*2.8%,IF(K2>=80%,J2*2.4%,IF(K2>=75%,J2*1.7%,IF(K2>=65%,J2*0.6%))))))`

Nested `IF` statements will always stop at the first statement it returns a "True" at. So by reversing the order you should be able to get the desired result for the `>=` comparison.